# Issues using BusterJS, ExpressJS, and SuperTest

Tags: node.js, express, supertest, buster.js

I'm having some issues testing routes using ExpressJS + BusterJS + SuperTest.

```
var app = require("../../app/app.js"),
buster = require("buster"),
expect = buster.referee.expect,
http = require('http'),
request = require('supertest');

buster.spec.expose();

describe("V2 API - group/get", function () {
    var server;

    beforeEach(function() {
        server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
            console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
        });
    });

    it("is accessable", function() {
        request(server)
          .get('/')
          .expect(200)
          .end(function(err, res){
             server.close();
             expect(err).toBe(null);
           });
    });
});
```

When I run this test, I get:

```
Failure: V2 API - group/get is accessible
No assertions!

1 test, 0 assertions, 1 runtime ... 1 failure
Express server listening on port 3000
```

Which seems wrong, because I actually do have an assertion.  The problem is that it doesn't get called unless there is an error.

Another issue is that if I have multiple 'if' blocks, the server doesn't restart between them.  I might be using the node + express + buster + supertest stack wrong, so any help with how to test these routes would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some code that doesn't have your problem; it does almost the same thing as yours but with asynchronous tests, e.g.

```
it("is accessable", function(done) {
    request(server)
      .get('/')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res){
         server.close();
         expect(err).toBe(null);
         done();
       });
});
```

I don't know enough about Buster to know if this is the "right way" to fix this issue, but hope it helps!

Comment: This answer got me on the right track.  I actually needed to use Buster's deferred promises.  After that, everything basically worked right.